# PHP Find the Index of the highest key value

Tags: php

I have an array of arrays. I would like to find the index of the array of the highest key value Rating. For example in the below the array index would be 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 array:3 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "name" => "Nola - Roman Road"
        "rating" => 4.2
        "price_level" => 3
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        "name" => "The Camel"
        "rating" => 4.6
        "price_level" => 2
      ]
      2 => array:3 [
        "name" => "The Dundee Arms"
        "rating" => 4
        "price_level" => 2
      ]
```

Comment: Why not an usual foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a few of the `array_...` functions.  First [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the column used for the maximum values, then [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to return all of the keys that match the maximum value (found using `max($prices)`)...

```
$data = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "Nola - Roman Road",
        "rating" => 4.2,
        "price_level" => 3
    ],
    1 => [
        "name" => "The Camel",
        "rating" => 4.6,
        "price_level" => 4
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "The Dundee Arms",
        "rating" => 4,
        "price_level" => 2
    ]];

$rating = array_column($data, "rating");
$index = array_keys($rating, max($rating));

print_r($index);
```

This prints out ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

This will also work if several entries match the maximum value which may help.

Comment: Funny how you extract the price_level while he asked for the highest rating. ;-)

Comment: @dnFer Ermmm.... I was more representing the idea 0:-/, although I have updated the answer.

Comment: Since all elements will have to be iterated over with a solution like this you **could** with a good conscience (regarding performance etc) just iterate over the array using a **foreach** loop and check the value. This could be preferred if you want some more elaborate logic for each iteration or for instance, not only track which index contains the highest rating but perhaps return a  reference to the actual element with the highest rating. If this was an array of objects, instead of arrays it often also presents a bit more freedom. But then something like **array_walk** often works fine to.

Comment: @inquam, you give some good information and there are usually a range of answers, each one gives benefits in different scenarios and with different criteria.  To try and provide every solution would sometimes become too confusing and at some point you have to go for a single solution.

Comment: @NigelRen: Of course, my comment was more to the original poster. So he would get some ideas on what to use for this and future similar situations. I didn't want to create an answer to write that since I think that your answer sums up a good solution for his current question.